# How exactly does the mechanic where El Presidente "boosts production" when he visits Dock work?

Tags: tropico-4, tropico-3

I was playing Tropico 3 and 4 for years and only recently noticed that El Presidente can visit the Docks (but not the Touring Docks), and apparently he "boosts production" there.

While I was using the presidential presence to improve the Farms, Mines, Schools, Clinics, Factories and other buildings all the time, I can notice the improvement of operation at the building's stats panel or/and indirectly, but what exactly does the presidential presence actually improve at the Docks?

[image: The Dock and El Presidente]

Comment: Which game, specifically, are you asking about? The answers might vary depending on which game you're playing.

Comment: @Joachim, thanks for all the missing "the"s! However, "boosts production" is literal in-game status I'm puzzled about, and "Dock" (singular) is specific building type causing it (there can be more than one).

Comment: @RavenDreamer, that was in the question tags, but I've edited to mention in the body too.

Comment: @FreeConsulting: Generally we ask for one question per post, and that questions be restricted to a single game + platform combo (unless it's asking about e.g. lore across a whole game series, or if it's provable that different series entries have the same answer). Ithink what Raven's getting at is that your question should only ask about either Tropico 3 OR 4; you can ask a separate question for each game.

Comment: I think *Tropico 3* and *4* are similar enough that this can be asked in one question.

Comment: I was also considering the possibility that one of the tags was possibly erroneous! Never hurts to ask for clarity!

Comment: I don't remember very clearly so I can't post this as an answer, but IIRC dock workers actually manually load the stuff to the ship. It is actually possible to not have enough time to load everything to the ship and thus when it sails, you still have some inventory left in the dock. Presidente visit boosts this loading speed

Comment: @Schism, I've observed the effect in question in both T3 and T4 and as @galacticninja noted, these games are very close to each other, specifically, Dock building only differs in cost and probably doors used by visitors. I think splitting the question will just make an exact dupe (unless someone would uncover a significant diffe). But feel free to zap `[tropico-3]` if you so wish.

Comment: @Raestloz, thanks for suggestion! Hmm, from my experience, Dockworkers are loading export good to the freighter by running a wheelbarrow from back door of that tri-sectioned warehouse to the crane at pier (I've added a screenshot) and back so whole process is quite speedy. But they are moving up to 1000 units of goods per run and doing up to 2 runs per work shift, maybe presidential presence improves these figures?

Comment: The Docks don't "produce" anything, but workers do need to actively work it to move goods from storage onto the ship for selling. That might be the boosted productivity (and trust me, I've had more than one endgame playthrough flounder not because I wasn't producing enough but because my dockworkers couldn't get it loaded into the trade ships before the ship left.)